# IA-32 assembly cpuid using printf

Tags: macos, assembly, x86

I'm trying to follow the book Professional Asssembly Language on Mac OS X Montain Lion. 
On google I found a port for Mac OS X at the following url: [Assembly on MacOS X](http://fabiensanglard.net/macosxassembly/index.php)

Created the file with Vim and compiled it with GAS:
as -g -arch i386 -o cpuid.o cpuid.s
Linked the code using gcc:
gcc -m32 -arch i386 -o cpuid cpuid.o

The resulting executable cpuid, runs without errors but if I try to debug it with gdb at the end it says Program exited with code 044 instead of Program exited normally.

Trying to find a way to make it exit correctly I've created an hello world example in C and generated assembly code it with:
gcc -Wall -03 -m32 -fno-PIC hello_pf.c -S -o hello_pf.s
The resulting assembly code is bellow:

```
.section        __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
        .globl  _main
        .align  4, 0x90
_main:  
        pushl   %ebp 
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $24, %esp
        leal    L_.str, %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    _puts
        movl    $0, -8(%ebp)
        movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
        movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
        addl    $24, %esp
        popl    %ebp
        ret

        .section        __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str: 
        .asciz   "Hello world!\n"


.subsections_via_symbols
```

- Can someone provide any help regarding this issue?
- How can I make a working version of cpuid from the link provided above using IA-32 mac ox s assembly?
- Where can I look for a detailed description of stack align problem in Mac OS X? I've read  what's on Apple site but for a beginner is not very helpful.
- What are for the instructions after call _puts from the above sample code?
- How does calling libc functions from assembly really works? Any good detailed articles on this topic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand the register usage in the calling conventions, a good place for that is

http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf

You will find that on Mac OS X 64-bit the return value for a function returning an "int" - such as main() - is in %rax.  You seem to want to use a 32-bit executable, in which case the return value is in %eax.  One convenient way to zero out a register is to XOR it with itself, so you should add this to the end of your routine:

```
xorl  %eax,%eax
```

That'll set %eax to zero, and that will be your exit code.

Comment: Putting the xorl %eax, %eax has no effect. The same message is given when running with gdb. I receive the same message: Program exited with code 044.

Comment: Figured it out how to make the program return Program exited normally.

Comment: Figured it out how to make the program return Program exited normally. Before calling _exit if I put a subl $12, %esp or addl $4, %esp and then pushl $0x0 the parameter for _exit function everything it's ok. But still not understanding why. Also an equivalent for the two instructions above is to add a movl $0, (%esp) before calling _exit. I understand the big picture, but I don't understand the mechanics behind. I'm missing some vital info and I cannot figure what?!